# Error in Intersect query in MariaDB without Intersect

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a problem with this query in MARIADB language.This query doesn't return anything but this query should return one line. What can i do to make it work?

```
`SELECT c.Raza, c.Nombre 
FROM caballos c JOIN caballodisciplina d 
ON c.Cod = d.Caballo 
WHERE d.Disciplina IN ('Salto fondo','Salto vertical') 
GROUP BY c.Raza, c.Nombre 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.Cod)=2`
```

the tables are as follows: 
[image]

[image]

and the query should return Nombre: Starlaight      Raza: Andaluz

Thanks!

Comment: Since the issue is not with the syntax of the query, but with what data it returns, you need to provide us with sample data, expected results based on the sample data, and the actual results you receive. Without these we can only guess what may have gone wrong.

Comment: I have already edited the question and you can see the tables and the result that should return the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query returns what it should (no result) because you join on the `caballos.Cod` field, and you filter on the distinct number of `Cod` fields being 2. Since the Cod field sems to be a unique identifier for `caballos` table and it is used in the join condition, it cannot have more than 1 distinct value per group.

You could use the `Disciplina` field in the filter criteria instead because it is only the `Disciplina` field that could have different values in 2 separate records in the resultset:

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT d.Disciplina)=2
```